# My Arduino + Ethernet shield WebServer sketch sometimes fails to connect to the client. Causes?

Tags: tcp, arduino, ethernet

My Arduino web server sketch sporadically fails on:

```
 EthernetClient client = server.available();
 if (client)
```

This morning, it connected just fine on the first run. Now, it can't connect to the client again. A couple of days ago, it worked several times, but failed several time as well. I have the shield connected via an Ethernet cable to my home router. I've verified the IP address assigned to the Arduino. I've tried ports 80 and 8080. What could be going wrong and what else can I try? Could my ISP be blocking something here? Please don't be afraid to suggest the obvious, since I know almost nothing about networks.

If relevant, here is a larger piece of the code, which loops on

```
Serial.println("Listening");
```

Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>n

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:

byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0xF7, 0x99 };
IPAddress ip(192,168,2,5);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

String roundOpenTag = "";
String roundCloseTag = "";

void setup()
{
    // Start the Ethernet connection and the server:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    server.begin();

    int ledPin = 8;
    // Initialize the digital pin as an output.
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Setting up");
}

void loop()
{
    // Listen for incoming clients
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    Serial.println("Listening");
    if (client)
    {
        Serial.println("Server available");
        // An HTTP request ends with a blank line
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
            Serial.println("Client connected");
            if (client.available())
            {
                char c = client.read();
```

I don't see the purpose in including the rest of the sketch. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I commented out  - Serial.begin(9600); - and all subsequent serial print outs, and it began working consistently again. I have no explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a empty Seiral.begin() in your setup() function. Try removing it.

**Edit**:

When you call Serial.begin() you have to provide the baut rate(speed) at which you want to communicate. You can read more about the function at [Arduino library page](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin).

You had two problems in your code

- You had a empty Serial.begin() function call, without any parameter
- You had duplicate Serial.begin() function. You had already specified it in the beginning of the setup() function.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. But what do you mean by 'empty'? I would like to be able to print out to serial in order to debug my code, but haven't been able to do that and keep my sketch working.

Comment: Updated the answer, to answer your query.

Comment: I have noticed that this question has been viewed quite a lot. I'd like to note that I never was able to connect to my client AND perform serial print outs together. It frustrates me that I never solved this, so if anyone reading knows the answer, please share.